# How to add class when meta tag has value

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to write the code that if the custom meta box that I wrote has value, then it should add class to a div or button. But I'm not sure if it's working because dreamweaver said that the code is incorrect or something...

Here's my code

```
<?php
    $offers = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'couponshortcode', true );
    if( $offers ) {
        echo "<button class="filter" data-filter=".couponclass"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i></button>";
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you can escape the double quotes? Or use single quotes to replace the outer double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use single quotes here:

```
<?php 
$offers = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'couponshortcode', true ); 
if( $offers ) { 
echo '
<button class="filter" data-filter=".couponclass">
<i class="fa fa-tags"></i>
</button>
'; 
} 
?>
```

**Second Solution:**

```
<?php 
$offers = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'couponshortcode', true ); 
if( $offers ) { 
?>
     <button class="filter" data-filter=".couponclass">
     <i class="fa fa-tags"></i>
     </button>
<?php
 } 
 ?>
```

And I am not sure about this dot 
`data-filter=".couponclass"`. Maybe its not required.